# Calculate correlation coefficients by creating a loop with numpy arrays of different dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, loops, correlation

I am working with two different arrays: x and y.

**Shape of x = (442,10)**

**Shape of y = (442,)**

I am trying to write a loop that prints the 10 correlation coefficients between y and the 10 features in x.

Here is my code:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

def np_corr(w, z):
    denom = (np.sqrt((len(z) * np.sum(w**2, axis=-1) - np.sum(w, axis=-1) ** 2)
                       * (len(z) * np.sum(z**2) - np.sum(z)**2)))
    return np.divide((len(z) * np.sum(w * z[None, :], axis=-1) - (np.sum(w, axis=-1) * np.sum(y))),
                     denom, where=denom!=0
                    )

corr = np_corr(swv(x, len(y)), y)
```

When running the code I get this error: Since axis is `None`, must provide window_shape for all dimensions of `x`; got 1 window_shape elements and `x.ndim` is 2.

Not sure how to fix it and if there is another way to do it.

Comment: Do you need a sliding window view? I can't exactly tell from the code, but your clarifying comments seem to suggest that you can get away with broadcasting instead: make y of shape (442, 1). If you want a sliding window view to work, then as the error mentions, pass an axis argument, or make the window shape something like (len(y), 1)

Comment: DON"T SUMMARIZE THE ERROR!

Comment: My guess (just a guess) is that the error occurs in the `swv` call.  If so check the docs.  Get that call right before trying to pass it on to your function.

Answer (score 1):

Your error:

```
In [41]: swv(np.ones((3,4)),4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[41], line 1
----> 1 swv(np.ones((3,4)),4)

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in sliding_window_view(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py:315, in sliding_window_view(x, window_shape, axis, subok, writeable)
    313     axis = tuple(range(x.ndim))
    314     if len(window_shape) != len(axis):
--> 315         raise ValueError(f'Since axis is `None`, must provide '
    316                          f'window_shape for all dimensions of `x`; '
    317                          f'got {len(window_shape)} window_shape elements '
    318                          f'and `x.ndim` is {x.ndim}.')
    319 else:
    320     axis = normalize_axis_tuple(axis, x.ndim, allow_duplicate=True)

ValueError: Since axis is `None`, must provide window_shape for all dimensions of `x`; got 1 window_shape elements and `x.ndim` is 2.
```

A call that works:

```
In [45]: swv(np.ones((3,4)),(2,2)).shape
Out[45]: (2, 3, 2, 2)
```

With a correction in the last line of your function:

```
In [48]: def np_corr(w, z):
    ...:     denom = (np.sqrt((len(z) * np.sum(w**2, axis=-1) - np.sum(w, axis=-1) ** 2)
    ...:                        * (len(z) * np.sum(z**2) - np.sum(z)**2)))
    ...:     return np.divide((len(z) * np.sum(w * z[None, :], axis=-1) - (np.sum(w, axis=-1) * np.sum(z))),
    ...:                      denom, where=denom!=0
    ...:                     )
    ...:
```

This runs:

```
In [49]: np_corr(np.arange(100).reshape(10,10), np.arange(10))
Out[49]: array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```